# Can I develop a LQR if the system is NOT controllable but stable?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-rank, simulation, optimal-control

I have this system.
[image]

It's a hydrulic piston which pushes a mass $M$ and that mass pushes a bending beam. The beam has a stiffness $k_3$ and a damping $b_2$ due to the rotation velocity and position.

And here is the equations for this system. Yes! I do not need to focus on the oil bulk modulus beacuse I going only to simulate a step function of the system. Not an impulse signal.

$$ \frac{1}{3}m_{2}L^{2}\ddot{\theta } = Lk_{_{2}}[y-Lsin(\theta )] -k_{3}\theta -b_{2}\dot{\theta } +\frac{1}{2}Lm_{2}gsin(\theta )\ $$

$$ \ M \ddot{y} = k_{1}(z - y) + b_{1}(\dot{z} - \dot{y}) - M g \mu \dot{y} -k_{2}[y-Lsin(\theta )] \ $$

$$ \ m_{1} \ddot{z} = -k_{1}(z-y) -b_{1}(\dot{z} - \dot{y}) + p_{p}A_{p} - p_{m}A_{m}\dot{z}\ $$

$p_m$ is the pressure at the piston's minus side.
$p_p$ is the pressure at the piston's plus side.
$\mu$ is the friction factor for the mass $M$.
$\frac{1}{3}m_{2}L^{2}\ddot{\theta }$ is the mass rotation inertia with the weight in the center. That's why $\frac{1}{3}$ are used.
$Lsin(\theta )$ is the length the top of the beam moves in horizontal direction

My question is....is this correct? I can simulate this system. It works! But this system only gives my NOT full rank when I try to check if this system is controllable. Do I miss an equation or equations?

I give you the matrix system writen in first order ODEs.
[image]

States are:
$$ z = x_1 , \dot{z} = x_2 $$
$$ y = x_3 , \dot{y} = x_4 $$
$$ \theta = x_5 , \dot{\theta} = x_6$$

I have choosen the values:

$$b_1 = 3000;
b_2 = 2000;
m_1 = 10;
m_2 = 7;
M = 2000;
g = 9.82;
mu = 0.3;
L = 0.1;
A_p = 0.004;
A_m = 0.002;
P_m = 1.5*10^6;
k_1 = 17777.77;
k_2 = 41824.95;
k_3 = 9170.76; $$

If i create a system **A** with a signalmatrix **B** 
$$\ A = \begin{bmatrix} 0& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0& \\ -1777.77& 600& 1777.77& 300& 0& 0&\\ 0& 0& 1& 0& 0& 0& \\ 8.88& 1.5& -29.80& -4.446& 2.09& 0& \\ 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 1& \\ 0& 0& 179249.8& 0& -410810.17& -85714.25& \end{bmatrix}\
$$

$$\ B = \begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 0.0004\\ 0\\ 0\\ 0\\ 0\\ \end{bmatrix}\
$$

This will give
$$rank(ctrb(A, B)) = 2 $$

But change **A** to

$$\ A = \begin{bmatrix} 0& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0& \\ -1777.77& 60& 1777.77& 300& 0& 0&\\ 0& 0& 1& 0& 0& 0& \\ 8.88& 1.5& -29.80& -4.446& 2.09& 0& \\ 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 1& \\ 0& 0& 179249.8& 0& -410810.17& -857& \end{bmatrix}\
$$

Will give me

$$rank(ctrb(A, B)) = 6 $$

as it should be!

**Question:**
Can I still develop a LQR regulator for this system, even if it's NOT controllable, but it's stable.

Try to run this code and you will see that the system is stable. If you don't have MATLAB, you can use Octave with the contol package. It's free and based on Matlab's control package.

```
A = [0 1 0 0 0 0; -3555.6 -1000 3555.6 600 0 0;0 0 0 1 0 0; 35.556 6 -119.206 -8.946 8.365 0; 0 0 0 0 0 1; 0 0 125475 0 -287560.2 -90000]
B = [0; 80; 0; 0; 0; 0];
C = [1 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 1 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 1 0]
D = 0;
sys = ss(A, B, C, D);
u = linspace(20, 20, 100);
t = linspace(0, 4, 100);
x0 = [0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0]
lsim(sys, u, t', x0')
rank(ctrb(A, B)) % This will gives 3. 
eig(A) % This will give all negative eigenvalues = Stable system
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between the concept of controllability and stabilizability. In stabilizability, there are states which are not reachable but already stable with -ve eigen value. For LQ control their the system needs to be stabilizable. Same goes for designing LQG. Then you need the system to be stabilizable and detectable ( equivat concept of observability).

Comment: Thank you! I got many questions about this. Perhaps you want to earn more points? I will accept.

Comment: I know this question/answer is old, but I am wondering 1) why does LQG require stabilizability and detectability and 2) how to check for stabilizability and detectability (specifically for nonlinear systems)? Do you have a reference paper/book you can provide, so I can find more details?

Comment: @Ralff: About NL systems, you can check out the book of Khalil (nonlinear systems or nonlinear control) and Arjan van der Schaft and Henk Nijmeijer wrote quite some works on controllability and observability of nonlinear systems. I remember there are some slides available on Arjan's website on nonlinear controllability. For LTI systems, check out the Hautus test